# Tag question: Two hours should be enough time, ________?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, tag-questions

The complete sentence is:

> Two hours should be enough time for passengers to travel from Taipei to Kaohsiung by high speed rail, **isn't it**?

Is it grammatically correct to use "isn't it" in the above sentence?
If not, how would you revise it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "isn't it?" "shouldn't it?" would be better, to avoid the switch in verb tense.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The original sentence is from a test in Taiwan and the correct answer is "isn't it?" There is no "shouldn't it" in the list of answers to choose from. Is it okay to use "isn't it"? I really need the opinions from native English speakers to confirm this confusion.

Comment: Then use what they tell you.

Comment: I've heard other Chinese speakers make the same mistake that the test makers have made. In this form of question, repeat and negate the same verb. "Does she or doesn't she? (Only her hairdresser knows for sure)." "Should he risk it, or shouldn't he?" "Can he make it? / No he can't." "Is dinner ready? / No it isn't."

Comment: *Shouldn't it* is the way to go; *isn't it* would work if the verb in the main sentence were ***is***. As a native speaker, I would not use *isn't it* with the original sentence.

Comment: Thank you all. Now there are 3-0 to clarify that "shouldn't it" is the correct answer. This is of great help to a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

The rule with these tag questions is that the verb in the tag echoes the tensed verb in the matrix clause if that is an auxiliary; if it is not an auxiliary, *do* is employed.

In this case, the tensed verb in the matrix clause is *should*, so the tag question should be *shouldn't it?*

Comment: There also seems to be a rule that the "subject" of the tag question must always be reduced to a simple pronoun. So it's ***That** looks easy, doesn't **it**?*, not *...doesn't **that**?*