# Question tags with should

Tags: tag-questions

What question tag should go with the following sentence:

> That should be easy.

Will it be **shouldn't that** or **shouldn't it** or something else, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag question: Two hours should be enough time, \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128067/tag-question-two-hours-should-be-enough-time) Specifically, [the tag question should be **shouldn't it?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/128071/126)

Comment: Thanks. The link given answers the query. How to close this question?

Comment: I believe that Fumble Fingers has flagged it (appears as the comment above and then has edited) this means it should be closed by the moderators. Otherwise, you can just delete the question.

Comment: As the OP (Original Poster) ***you*** can delete your own question. But I think it's better if you don't, because when *future* visitors come here looking for help with the same problem, it's easier for them to find the (hopefully, ***best***) answer if the question has been asked multiple times. Maybe just because different people use different phrasing to ask about the same thing, so there's more chance that a simple text search will find at least *one* relevant question on the relkevant topic.

Comment: ...I'll even give you an ***upvote*** here as a "reward" for posting a question at all. Some people might consider *downvoting,* to "punish" you for failing to search properly for an existing question before posting yours, but I'm not generally in that camp. It's not always easy to find relevant earlier questions even if you ***do*** try hard. And there is the rarely-mentioned issue of *Why is the tag question **shouldn't it**? rather than **shouldn't that**?*.